# Indent all elements under headdings by different amounts - CSS

Tags: css, padding, siblings

I am trying to indent elements based on the heading tag they are under. I am doing this currently by using the sibling selector:

```
p{
    padding-left: 0;
}

h1 + p, h1 + ul{
    padding-left: 1em;
}

h2 + p{
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```

However if have two or more paragraphs under a heading then the padding defaults back to zero.

Is there a way to set padding of all elements under h1 tag to the same value and all elements under the h1 tag to a different value (only using CSS)?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```css
h1+div {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
h2+div {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
<div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<h2>My Title</h2>
<div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

There is also a way to achieve the same effect using only CSS, but I wont especially reccommend it:

```css
h1 ~ p, h1 ~ ul {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

h2 ~ p, h2 ~ ul {
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>My title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

<h2>My title</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: This works of course, but the question asked for a CSS-only solution (not CSS+HTML).

Comment: You are right, I added the pure CSS version. Probably not what I would reccomend as it indents everything on the page thats comes after the `h1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason I want it to be completely in CSS is that I am using CSS to style markdown. I want to be able to write only markdown and CSS

Comment: Problem with this answer is also that when you go back to using h1 the indent of h2 remains.